# Inefficient CSS selector suggestions

Tags: html, css, browser, css-selectors

I got 2 questions about refactoring our legacy CSS for performance improvement.

(1) The following **printer-related** CSS is included in a common.css and some elements apply the selectors. Does it affect browser rendering performance? In other words, other than printing the page, do the browsers use the CSS to check whether an element matches the selectors?

```
@media print
{
    body * {visibility:hidden}
    #xView, #xView * {visibility:visible; }
    #xView {position:fixed;}
}
```

(2) How do I evaluate the performance improvement after refacotring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a big piece of code, so talking about performance seems a little bit offtopic, but still - if you are using "*" selector, it won't be very fast. It would be much better if you've set visibility to one container than to every element inside it.

For the topic of performance testing - a good read:

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

http://blog.archive.jpsykes.com/151/testing-css-performance/

You could also test the page load times in Firebug, but I don;t know how accurate results will be.

Answer (score 1):

1: No, the `print` CSS is only applied when printing, so no checks against any code in their is done before printing.

2: For measuring CSS performance, have a look at this [test harness for CSS](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2010/11/css-performance-part-1/).